# SSL - Internal Server Error in PHP

Tags: php, ssl

I just installed Godaddy SSL to my VPS.

but when I run php files on https , i get Internal server error.

what may cause this ?

Comment: My PHP version is 5.3

Comment: We would need much more information to answer this, are there any messages logged, does it work without ssl, what should the code do, do static pages work, what os and web server is this running on.

Comment: Everything works fine on normal HTTP but PHP doesnt work on HTTPS. Static pages works great on HTTPS. Runs on APACHE. And PHP 5.3

Comment: Do you have access to the apache logs? The answer is probably in there.

Comment: i can see error and access logs only

Comment: You will find the cause for the internal server error in your Apache httpd's error log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of errors reported as "Internal Server Error" are shown in the web-server's error log.

Causes vary widely, for example the PHP script might not have the correct access permissions.